# Using Excel Functions to Get Data into a Single Cell

Tags: arrays, excel, add-in, bloomberg

I'm working with the Bloomberg Add-in on Excel to gather some data. The problem I'm having is to get all the data into a single cell. For instance, I want to get the daily change % for the past 5 fives for IBM. The formula I am using is:

```
=BDH("IBM US Equity","CHG_PCT_1D","11/9/2012","","Array","TRUE")
```

I made this using the Formula Builder, so I'm not sure why this isn't working. It returns error message: "#N/A Invalid Parameter: Invalid Override Field ID Specified"

If I exclude the whole array part, then it returns the data I want but in 1827 or so different cells. Any way I can get all of these in one cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the working method that fills cells **A1** through **A1827**.
Then in cell **B1** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A1:A1827)
```

This cell will contain all the data you require.

Comment: Yes that would work, but my main concern was that applying this function to many tickers would cause me to surpass the daily Bloomberg data pull limit :/

Comment: I've been told pulling data into one cell would avoid this; not sure whether or not if this is true though

Comment: @V.Youn It makes no difference with regards to daily limit - your BDH, even if it fills 1,827 cells, is still regarded as a single query. And the limit is quite high (I think 100k queries).

Comment: A hit is calculated as one field for one security on one day. You get "charged" the same if you do many hits in one formula or many hits in many formulae.

Comment: Oh I see, looks like I was given some misinformation from the start. Thank you!